# Why don’t we have to call main function in C?

Tags: c, function

I just had a question that whenever I write code I  had to call all functions (predefined or user defined) in order to use or execute them. So why we don't have to call main function?

Comment: The `main` function is where the program begins execution.  That is ingrained into the language.

Comment: [In C, how is the main() method initially called?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3469955)

Comment: On a hosted implementation (basically, anything with an operating system), the host environment calls `main` when you invoke the program.  On a freestanding environment (i.e., an embedded system), the program entry point doesn't have to be `main`.

Comment: There has to be one function not called by your code but by something else. Otherwise how would your code start executing?

Comment: main() is meant for the operating system to call. See Linux source for how it starts a program.

Answer (score 2):

The `main` function is defined by the [language itself](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) as the designated start of the program. You don't need to call it because, in effect, your operating system (Linux, macOS, Windows, etc.) does.